# adding a string to an empty array gives `NAN`

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, vector

In MATLAB, I would like to iteratively add string to array `s`, and I initialized `s` by `s = []`. However, when I run the code below

```
s = [];
s(end+1) = "a";
s(end+1) = "b";
```

it results in

```
>> s

s =

   NaN   NaN
```

Does anyone know the reason behind and any workaround for this issue?

---

However, when I have already `""` in `s`, i.e., `s = [""]`, then all the following elements can added to `s` without problem:

```
s = [""];
s(end+1) = "a";
s(end+1) = "b";
```

gives

```
s = 

  1×3 string array

    ""    "a"    "b"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you initialize a new array:

```
s = []
```

`s` is, by default, of class double.

So when you try to add a new string in this array, matlab try to do an implicit casting `string -> double`. And matlab output a `NaN` when it has to deal with a  `string -> double` conversion (except if this string can be interpreted as a number [as mentionned by @CrisLuengo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67385933/4363864)). For example:

```
double("a") 
% Produce Nan
```

Instead of initializing your array with `[]`, you can explicitly choose the datatype of your array with `strings`:

```
s = strings(0); % We create a 0x0 strings array. 
s(end+1) = "a";
s(end+1) = "b";
```

And we get:

```
s = 

  1×2 string array

    "a"    "b"
```

When you initialize an array already containing an empty string, matlab understand that it needs to produce a strings array.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

To add to [obchardon’s correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67385729/7328782) (read that first!):

1. Converting a string to double produces NaN when the string cannot be interpreted as a number. `double("1")` returns 1.
2. There is a difference between *string* and *char array*. OP’s code would work fine after replacing `"` with `'`, as characters can always be converted to double (resulting in their ASCII value). But then it only works with single characters, multiple characters (an array of characters) would cast to an array of doubles, one per character, and that wouldn’t fit into a single array element.

   ```matlab
   >> s = [];
   >> s(end+1) = 'a';
   >> s(end+1) = 'b';
   >> s
   s =
       97    98
   ```